Why does stderr output not appear after I clear the terminal through stdout?
I want to print an error after clearing the terminal, but the error does not appear:
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    
    printf("\033[2J\033[1;1H");
    fprintf(stderr, "error !\n");
    return 0;
}

It's working perfectly with stdout, and if I first print something in stdout and next in stderr, it works.
I've tried with  printf("\033[2J\033[1;1H"); to clear the terminal, it's the same problem.
Is there a way to do this?

Why would you mix stdout and stderr in this way? Either you treat stdout and stderr as independent streams, or you only use one of them.

You are suffering from buffering.
By default,

stdout is line-buffered if connected to a terminal.
stdout is block-buffered otherwise.
stderr isn't buffered.
Other handles are block-buffered.

(This isn't mandated by C, but it's recommended, and it's what you get from the major C libraries on the major OSs.)
Some definitions:

Block-buffered: Output is sent to the OS when the buffer becomes full, and when the handle is closed.
Line-buffered: Output is sent to the OS when the buffer becomes full, when a line-feed is written, and when the handle is closed.
Not buffered: Output is sent to the OS immediately.

Since you didn't fill stdout's buffer, and due to the lack of a line feed in what you printed, the printf outputs nothing to the OS. The control sequences are only output to the OS when the handle is closed when the program exits, after you printed the message to stderr.
Flushing stdout's buffer before printing to stderr will address the issue.
printf("\033[2J\033[1;1H");
fflush(stdout);  // Send everything that's in the buffer to the OS *now*.
fprintf(stderr, "error !\n");


TIL!  What's the rationale behind stderr being unbuffered?

@DanielWalker: Probably the most important is that when the program crashes, anything trapped in buffers is lost and stderr is often used to print important information when a process experiences a fatal error (as well as at other times).  It's not even so easy as "just tell the programmer to call fflush(stderr) after the logging", because when the data structures are corrupt, the logging code may itself crash in the middle, and you still want to get everything up to that point.

Also, as a channel for error messages, the amount of data written to it is typically very low, so there's no penalty to avoid the buffering.

@ikegami, ...well -- I wouldn't describe it as a channel for error messages only, being intended for general diagnostic use (logs meant for human readers f/e). Still, generally a set of logging small enough that humans can realistically process it is fairly well size-constrained. :)

Re “This isn't mandated by C”: C 2018 specifies buffering requirements for standard output and standard error in 7.21.3 7. It is not as strict as what you list, but standard error must not be fully buffered (so, for example, any error messages ending with a new-line must be sent immediately), and standard output must be fully buffered if it can be determined not to refer to an interactive device and not fully buffered otherwise. Re “it's what you get from the major compilers”: This is typically implemented in the library, not the compiler.

@Eric Postpischil, Re "It is not as strict as what you list", ...which is why I said it isn't mandated by C. /// Re "This is typically implemented in the library", ...which is provided by the compiler.

@ikegami: The library and the compiler are separate things. E.g., GCC and the GNU C Library are separate projects. GCC documentation says “GCC does not provide the library facilities required only of hosted implementations, nor yet all the facilities required by C99 of freestanding implementations on all platforms. To use the facilities of a hosted environment, you need to find them elsewhere (for example, in the GNU C library).”

That might matter if you installed from source. But otherwise, you get the C lib when you install gcc.
